# Why there is "Difference in Response Headers" from two differnt servers?

Tags: rest, header, response, content-type

**Response Header From Server 1**

```css
Access-Control-Allow-Head... Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Meth... GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Content-Length 649
Content-Type application/json
Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie cmx-token=TKFqbwbCuPzKaxSu1aqu9+QnW2AJTvOooUzmMGg2TYQ=;Path=/
X-TOTAL-EXECUTION-TIME 0
access-control-allow-orig... *
view source
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie _ga=GA1.1.1917656998.1416163342; cmx-token=TKFqbwbCuPzKaxSu1aqu9+QnW2AJTvOol2qKvN85gLY=; cmx.user=%7B%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22username%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22password%22%3Anull%2C%22sessionId%22%3Anull%2C%22loggedIn%22%3Atrue%2C%22remember%22%3Afalse%2C%22userGroups%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22roles%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22loginData%22%3Anull%7D; usageStatistics=%7B%22consent%22%3Afalse%2C%22lastConsentDate%22%3A1421653154045%7D
Host 172.19.35.217
Referer http://172.19.35.217/manage/
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
```

**Response Header from Server 2**

```css
Access-Control-Allow-Head... Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Meth... GET, POST, DELETE, PUT
Content-Length 18
Set-Cookie cmx-token=TKFqbwbCuPzIojRpj8Q+EOQnW2AJTvOobh5OPVbQTYM=;Path=/
X-TOTAL-EXECUTION-TIME 0
access-control-allow-orig... *
view source
Accept application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cookie _ga=GA1.1.149330011.1415357352; cmx-token=TKFqbwbCuPzIojRpj8Q+EOQnW2AJTvOoTbX4WoGo39w=; cmx.user=%7B%22id%22%3Anull%2C%22username%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22password%22%3Anull%2C%22sessionId%22%3Anull%2C%22loggedIn%22%3Atrue%2C%22remember%22%3Afalse%2C%22userGroups%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22roles%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22loginData%22%3Anull%7D; usageStatistics=%7B%22consent%22%3Afalse%2C%22lastConsentDate%22%3A1421652985433%7D
Host 172.19.35.186
Referer http://172.19.35.186/manage/
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:35.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/35.0
X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest
```

Hi all,

I have same application code deployed on two different servers. Application is based on RESTFUL we b services. 
On UI, one of the server "404 Not Found exception" and other works. 
I have attached two Code spinets. 
There is no "content-type" property in response header for one server.
The other one sends content-type as application/json.

What should be the reason for such deviation in response ?
The only difference is the deployed servers, am i missing any kind of configuration here?

Comment: Can you specify the two server configuration? Is server 1 failing or server 2?

Comment: First - Linux cmx-vmdev88 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.  Second - Linux cmx-vmdev8 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Nov 22 03:15:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: But i think you need server configuration, well i can't give that configuration.

Comment: What I mean by "Configuration" is the language, framework used on your server (PHP, Node.js...), and can you post the code generating the answer?